# BUILD_LOG email output is not including error text from console log

Tags: email, logging, jenkins-plugins

I am using the Jenkins emailext plugin and trying to receive console output but only receive a truncated log w/o the actual error.

I am forcing an assert to fail on purpose to test that I receive failure log ($BUILD_LOG) in my email. I do get MOST of the log but not the actual final error or last few steps.  Is there a way to capture the error?  It is sending a truncated version of the log which does not include the last few steps because I suspect that when it does the mail send it sends what it has collected so far (up to the mailext step) and the final steps are not written into the log yet since we are at emailext step. But, unfortunately, the actual error is written to the end of the log so I never get to see it in the email.  I don't really care that I lose the final steps, I care that I don't end up seeing my error message which is the whole point of sending the logs.  I want to be able to see errors in email when I am not on VPN and able to access Jenkins. 
Is there an environment variable that contains the ERROR or a way to flush the error before the end of file is reached?

`post {
    failure {
        emailext (to: xyz@acmeinc.com", subject: "Failed Pipeline: ${currentBuild.fullDisplayName}", body: """Something went wrong with ${env.BUILD_URL}\n\n\${BUILD_LOG, maxLines=500, escapeHtml=false}""")
    }
}`

> Started by userxxx
>   ...
>   [Pipeline]
>   emailext
>   Sending email to: abc@acmeinc.com
>   [Pipeline] }
>   [Pipeline] // stage
>   [Pipeline] }
>   [Pipeline] // node
>   [Pipeline] End of Pipeline
>   groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: IE_BUILDx for class: groovy.lang.Binding...

What I care about is the error displayed at the end of the pipeline steps (e.g. No such property error) - is there a way to force that to flush to the log before I send my mail to to capture it any other way?

Since this is a declarative pipeline I cannot put try/catch around whole block.  I can put try/catch  around each script section in my pipeline to catch the error, save the error messages in a variable for my email and re-throw the error but that is very tedious and clutters the code

Comment: I ended up doing what I mentioned above. I added a try/catch around each script section and I process and re-throw the error so it shows up in my final emails.